# How to print crystal report without opening the report in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I want to print the crystal report with out previewing the report first?

Edited.
note that :

I want the client to print the report from his machine not from the server printer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691452%28VS.71%29.aspx) for that.

Comment: thanks for that but I don't want to use this method because I want the client to print the report from his machine not from the server printer.