# How to print crystal report directly to a client machine using C# Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I need to print a Crystal report page to client printer machine  without showing the report or without showing any dialog box.

One point I'd like to mention is that I know the name of Client Printer.
How do I send the path to that printer.

Just to make it clear the application runs on a server machine in a remote location.

There are some similar question here , but WITHOUT any final solution,like this one.

[How to print crystal report without opening the report in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378021/how-to-print-crystal-report-without-opening-the-report-in-asp-net)

Is there a specific solution to this  that I can use ?

Answer (score 3):

Below line opens up print dialog box to print without showing print preview
crystalReportViewer1.PrintReport();

Below line directly sends reportdocument to default printer.

oReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(1,true,0,0);

Comment: This will work in desktop only . I am looking for a solution in ASP.net. I need to print the report from a client machine printer.

Comment: you have to populate report data on Page_Init and use oReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(1,true,0,0);