# Print Crystal Report Directly in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am populating data in Crystal Report using SQL Server stored procedures. I was able to achieve my desired printing output using parameters passing and formatting each column using formula in CR.

In printing reports, the usual process is it will preview the created / generated output in Crystal Report Viewer, then, there are the print, export options where it will convert first the report to PDF to proceed to the printing functions

What I want is when I click the print button, It will automatically lead to printing procedures.

I was lead to this link for the answer [How to print crystal report directly to a client machine using C# Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849546/how-to-print-crystal-report-directly-to-a-client-machine-using-c-sharp-asp-net)

```
using oReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(1,true,0,0);
```

code, others also suggesting to fill the dataset in page init, but I am seem lost on how to do it.

This is my currently working code (the usual printing process where it will lead you first to the Crystal Report preview.

```
public partial class Report_MonthlySalesReportPrint : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();

        //Parameters to be passed as needed in formulas in Report
        string RP = Session["RP"].ToString();
        DateTime cms = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["CurrentMonthStart"].ToString());
        string Loc = Session["Location"].ToString();
        string MonthCurrent = Session["MonthCurrent"].ToString();
        string YearCurrent = Session["YearCurrent"].ToString();
        string MonthPrevious = Session["MonthPrevious"].ToString();
        string YearPrevious = Session["YearPrevious"].ToString();
        string MonthLastYear = Session["MonthLastYear"].ToString();
        string YearLastYear = Session["YearLastYear"].ToString();

        report.Load(Server.MapPath("MSRC.rpt"));

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh = true;
        CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();

        report.SetParameterValue(0, MonthLastYear);
        report.SetParameterValue(1, MonthCurrent);
        report.SetParameterValue(2, MonthPrevious);
        report.SetParameterValue(3, RP);
        report.SetParameterValue(4, Loc);
        report.SetParameterValue(5, cms);
        report.SetParameterValue(6, YearCurrent);
        report.SetParameterValue(7, YearPrevious);
        report.SetParameterValue(8, YearLastYear);

        report.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 0, 0);
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

UPDATED:

I just needed this to update for clarification purposes that the accepted answer below will work only on server side. Meaning when user is accessing the server remotely, the code will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. CLIENT-SIDE PRINTING**

This is the most ideal method in printing in a Web-based application as most users will be certainly accessing the server remotely.

Put this javascript code inside the head tag of your .aspx page where the crystal report viewer resides.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">


                function Print() {
                      var dvReport = document.getElementById("dvReport");
                      var frame1 = dvReport.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
                      if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Internet Explorer") != -1) {
                          frame1.name = frame1.id;
                          window.frames[frame1.id].focus();
                          window.frames[frame1.id].print();
                      }
                      else {
                          var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
                          frameDoc.print();
                      }
                  }
            </script>
```

With the same page, in the body tag put this

```
  <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print Directly" OnClientClick="Print()"></asp:Button>

          <div id="dvReport">
            <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" ToolPanelView="None" EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="false"  />


          </div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

--
  take note of the button in there. it should be outside the div that enclosed the crystal report viewer. This will surely work. see Full discussion on this method: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Print-Crystal-Report-on-Client-Side-on-Button-Click-using-JavaScript-in-ASPNet.aspx

---

**2. SERVER SIDE PRINTING**

The most suggested answers here is the **printToPrinter() Function**. This method is done on server-side, hence, it is limited when  you are accessing the server of your Web-based application / website remotely, unless the client can map or have the access with the server printer.

---

Please read this for further info: http://aspalliance.com/509_Automatically_Printing_Crystal_Reports_in_ASPNET.3

Answer (score 3):

```
       using System.Drawing.Printing;
       using Crystal Decisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
       using Crystal Decisions.Shared;
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         void();
       }
       public void()
       {
         try
        {
         ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
         crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport2.rpt"));
         DataSet dsCustomers = GetData("select * from visitor_details where  id ='" + Session["sessionvid"] + "' and  plant ='" + Session["sessionplant"] + "'");

         DataTable dataTable = dsCustomers.Tables[0];   crystalReport.Database.Tables["visitor_details"].SetDataSource((DataTable)dataTable);
          CrystalReportViewer2.ReportSource = crystalReport;
          CrystalReportViewer2.Zoom(100);
          //crystalReportViewer1.ExportReport() ;
          CrystalReportViewer2.RefreshReport();
          crystalReport.PrintOptions.PrinterName = GetDefaultPrinter();
          crystalReport.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
        }
        catch
        {
            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('connect printer settings')</script>");
        }
```

}

Comment: hi @balajibran ,  we almost have the same codes based on what I have posted. the only difference is that i don't use dataset and datatable. I followed your suggestion by putting crystalReport.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0); only in my current code, but nothing's changed it is previewing to crystal report viewer still.

Comment: good news, this already worked for me, the only problem a while ago is that I was not connected to the right printer. However, I have few more queries, How can I set this up where in a printer dialog box to be shows first before printing immediately, I mean i need that to set the paper size and generally to inform the user that is is printing.

Comment: I've voted for this as this answers the problem, however what I wanted is a PRINT DIALOG should pop up first to select a printer available , because with the code we used, it literally prints the report directly and immediately. I need a print dialog box for a more flexible printing options. How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This works for me. You can create your own `PageSettings` if needed, else just use an emtpy one.

If you want to open a print dialogue, simply use `PrintDialog`;

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

//...

ReportClass report = new ReportClass();
report.FileName = @"C:/Layout.rpt";
report.Load();
report.SetDataSource(YourSource);

PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();

PrintDialog pdialog = new PrintDialog();
if (pdialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    settings = pdialog.PrinterSettings;
}

report.PrintToPrinter(settings, new PageSettings() { }, false);
```

Comment: Hi @DionV. on the printername, should I put the actual complete printer name? also to the datasourcename, what should I do if I'm not using dataset and my datasources comes directly from stored procedure?

Comment: @rickyProgrammer yes, the full printername. The `SetDataSource` method also accepts `DataTable` or even an `IEnumerable`. If your data comes from a Stored Procedure you will probably get `DataTable`.

Comment: I have already solve the problem using  crystalReport.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0); I just include that in my code posted above and it literally prints the page directly, however what I wanted is for a print dialog box to be poped up first to select printer.

Comment: I am trying the codes but PrintDialog is red lined. Am I missing a type or namespace declaration? I already have these two as my namespaces using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Drawing;

Comment: @ricktProgrammer yes, you need System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: It actually worked! I copied or used your code from Printersetting below and put it on my code above. It actually works, However I have issues on the process, because the print dialog is not opening on the page itself it is like a window based and I have to close the browser to find the print dialog, Are there ways to correct this and make it more presentable?

Comment: @rickyProgrammer you can try something with Forms and `BringToFront()`, but that's another question and you can easily find the answer on Google :)

Comment: Hi @DionV There are problems with the code I just found out. 1. When I click print, yes it shows the print dialog , but it is shown at the bottom part, ideally it has to be topmost where the page to be printed is. 2. the printing continues even I decided to click CANCEL in the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

```
            CrystalReportSaleSlip _CrystalReportSaleSlip = new CrystalReportSaleSlip();
            _CrystalReportSaleSlip.SetDataSource(dtReport);

            _CrystalReportSaleSlip.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "Hp Laserjet M1522 MFP Series PCL 6";
            _CrystalReportSaleSlip.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

PrintToPrinter will work only if the printer is configured in the Server. From client, this might not work as the printer might not be listed