# How to print crystal report directly to the client's printer?

Tags: asp.net, printing, crystal-reports

I know this question is already being asked by other user on SO. But, I am not about to ask the same question. When I have searched this question I have found lots of link for the same issue. for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7849546/3761928) question. But, nobody has given correct solution for this question.

Actually `CrystalReport.PrintToPrinter()` method gets executed on server side. So, when the method is executed it will print the data on server's printer. not on client's printer. Somebody has also suggested that share a client's printer and assign the shared printer name to the `CrystalReport's PrinterName` property. But, it is only possible when the machines are connected to each other by LAN. What happen when the client is trying to print the report over the internet network?

> So, I am wondering about if it is possible that i can send the print data to the client's machine without notifying popup window and sends it to the client's default printer.

Answer (score 0):

I only know a commercial product that can help you do this. You can find a tutorial for it [here](http://www.neodynamic.com/articles/How-to-Directly-Print-Crystal-Reports-to-Default-Client-Printer-from-ASP-NET-without-Preview-or-Printer-Dialog/).